# PHP MySQL query in for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to run a while loop into a for loop to check something and I have this:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i++) {
while($c_cross = mysqli_fetch_array($ccc_cross)) {
    $d = explode("-", $c_cross['data']);
    $d1 = ltrim($d[2], 0);
    if($d1 == $i)
       echo "something";
    $count++;
    $sumaCross = $sumaCross + $c_cross['ccc_cross'];
    $sume[] = $c_cross['ccc_cross'];
}
```

}

I want to check if the **$c_cross['data']** is equal to my **$i** variable and `if so, echo something`. **The problem is that while loop runs only once**, **for $i = 1** and then stops. Any ideas of how I can do this ?

Comment: what's the value of `$days`?

Comment: The number of days of current month, 31 in this case.

Comment: just to be sure - does `echo $days` shows 31?

Comment: Yes, `echo $days` shows 31.

Comment: and still, try to print `echo mysqli_num_rows($ccc_cross)` before the loop

Comment: try this one: $d1 = ltrim($d[2], '0');

Comment: What for skparwal ? The trim works, I need to loop through all days and check each day if the date from my db is equal to day number.

Comment: _“The problem is that while loop runs only once, for $i = 1 and then stops”_ – I hope you know _why_ it does this? If you do, then you should already know a possible solution as well – reset the result pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Place your `for` loop inside `while` loop ...

```
while($c_cross = mysqli_fetch_array($ccc_cross)) {
    $d = explode("-", $c_cross['data']);
    $d1 = ltrim($d[2], 0);
    for($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i++) {
        if($d1 == $i)
            echo "something";
    }
    $count++;
    $sumaCross = $sumaCross + $c_cross['ccc_cross'];
    $sume[] = $c_cross['ccc_cross'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use mysqli_fetch_array outside for loop. For second time mysqli_fetch_array for same result will return empty.

or try to execute query in for loop every time.